# Div float: right being pushed down to bottom

Tags: html, css

On this page, I have the following code:

```
<div id="twitter">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="twitter_div">
                            ...
            <span class="tweet-author">via <a href="https://twitter.com/WhiteWreath" title="WhiteWreath" target="_blank">WhiteWreath</a></span>
        </div>                      
    </div>
    <div class="facebook_div">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WhiteWreath/" title="Follow us on Facebook"><img src="http://www.whitewreath.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/facebook-icon.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to float the Facebook icon (`.facebook_div`) so it is flush with the right hand side of `.twitter_div` and level with the top of `.twitter_div`.

However, it is being pushed down to level with the bottom of `.twitter_div`.

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
#header #twitter {width: 485px;}
.twitter_div {float: right; padding-right: 32px;}
.facebook_div {float: right;}
```

Help appreciated. [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/8331fxxu/14/). Having a bit of trouble replicating live code on the jsfiddle.

Please not: the HTML cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'inverted order' is the intended result.

You can dig around in the [CSS Specification for floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) if you'd like, but your example renders as it ought to.

If you'd like them to display in the same order as the markup, `float the .inner to right`, and its `children (.twitter_div and . facebook_div) to left`.

**[Fiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/8331fxxu/16/)**

**Updated Answer:**

I reviewed your given link, below are the findings,

You have to add "width" to twitter_div and remove its "padding-right". Also add "padding-top" to facebook_div.

You can add `width:330px;` to twitter_div and `padding-top:1em;` to facebook_div. It will align both divs next to each other

Comment: Thanks Mazzu. I've done that, but on the [live site](http://www.whitewreath.com/) the effect is a bit different.

Comment: Steve, Can you share the actual link?

Comment: Alright! Steve you have add "width" to twitter_div and remove its "padding-right". Also add "padding-top" to facebook_div.

Comment: You can add "width:330px;" to twitter_div and "padding-top:1em" to facebook_div. It will align both divs next to each other

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vuuhg5u9/)

i have updated you html content little bit and css to it

```
<div id="twitter">

<div class="facebook_div">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WhiteWreath/" title="Follow us on Facebook"><img src="http://www.whitewreath.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/facebook-icon.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <div class="twitter_div">
                        ...
        <span class="tweet-author">via <a href="https://twitter.com/WhiteWreath" title="WhiteWreath" target="_blank">WhiteWreath</a></span>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

CSS File

```
    .twitter_div {float: right; padding-right: 32px;}
.facebook_div {float: right;}
#twitter{float: left;width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks Jayant. Updated my question: HTML cannot be changed thanks.

Comment: If you are using `float:right` you have to put facebook div before the text

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear your scenario, but here is possible solution:

```
.inner { float:right; }
.facebook_div { float: right; }
.twitter_div { display:inline-block; padding:5px 10px 0 0; }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8331fxxu/15/

Answer (score 0):

you are using `<div>` it's a block level element so when ever you will use it. it will take whole row on which you will use it next `<div>` will go to next line there are different method to solve this problem simplest one is use `<span>` tag second time not `<div>`. `<span>` is a inline element `Float:right` will work for you

Comment: Incorrect Mirza, a `<div>` element can have a width attribute, meaning it will not take up the whole row. :-)

Comment: yes you are right but in more general concept without width it will take whole row

Comment: well, okay, but my example is using widths, so it is not sensible to talk about general concept, when the specific example does not need it.